# Unhandled 'error' event in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, npm, wkhtmltopdf, fs

I'm working in NodeJs and when trying to write file as .pdf with the help of 'fs' npm package I got some error and even pdf is not generating. I need help to jump out of this, issue is

```
    events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:833:14)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:456:5)
    at _destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:40:7)
    at Socket._destroy (net.js:603:3)
    at Socket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:32:8)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:835:10)
```

Code regarding this error:

```
let doc = await wkhtmltopdf(options, xxxx);
let file = await doc.stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/${id}_init.pdf`));
```

Thanks in anticipation!!
I have tried re-installing fs package, changing the ports but no improvement
I think the issue may be bcz of wkhtmltopdf package too(I'm using Mac)

Comment: Please post the relevant code too, not just the error.

Comment: You definitely don't need to install `fs` from npm, by the way; it's a built-in module. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: Okay.. Is this issue is bcz of wkhtmltopdf? I think so

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make the following changes, this is working very nicely for me:

```
// Set url and options to whatever you wish
let doc = wkhtmltopdf(url, options);
let file = doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/${id}_init.pdf`));
```

We can't use await on either call, since neither wkhtmltopdf nor doc.pipe return promises.

You can also try writing directly to file, skipping the stream, e.g.

```
wkhtmltopdf('http://google.com/', { output: 'out.pdf' });
```

Comment: Thanks @Terry, but its not working for me, its generating the empty pdf as of now

Comment: Does it work when you try another Url? Say Google ? I'm just wondering if the problem is specific to the Url you are targeting.

Comment: Yep, thank you so much @Terry for ur time and response, the issue is because Mac need to install wkhtmltopdf like ```brew cask install wkhtmltopdf```